# Typescript get day of timestamp

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, timestamp

```
console.log("----  " + this.sessionData.getUser().getLastQuizDone());
console.log(new Date(this.sessionData.getUser().getLastQuizDone()).getDay());
```

output is:

```
----  Timestamp(seconds=1539208800, nanoseconds=0) profile.ts:73:6
NaN
```

Question: How do I get the day/month/year from `timestamp`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `getLastQuizDone` returns some kind of Timestamp instance instead of actual timestamp. Could you get an actual timestamp from it?

Probably it could work:

```
new Date(this.sessionData.getUser().getLastQuizDone().seconds * 1000).getDay()
```

Comment: .seconds: `[ts] Property 'seconds' does not exist on type 'Date'.`
getSeconds():  `_this.sessionData.getUser(...).getLastQuizDone(...).getSeconds is not a function`

Comment: @farahm what does `getLastQuizDone` method return?

Comment: `getLastQuizDone(): Date{return this.lastQuizDone;}`

Comment: @farahm `lastQuizDone` is instance of Date?

Comment: Then this should work: `this.sessionData.getUser().getLastQuizDone().getDay()`

Comment: `_this.sessionData.getUser(...).getLastQuizDone(...).getDay is not a function`